# trying to find the value is numeric or integer from string

Tags: coldfusion

With the url string below, I need to find the value of the parameter named `construction`.

```
<cfset understand = "http://www.example.com/ops.cfm?id=code&construction=148&construction=150&Building=852&Building=665&Building=348&Building=619&Building=625&Building=626&_=1426353166006&action=SUBMIT">

<cfset understand2 = "http://www.example.com/ops.cfm?id=code&construction=AVENT+Construction+Site&construction=Signore+upper+constructions&Building=852&Building=665&Building=348&Building=619&Building=625&Building=626&_=1426353166006&action=SUBMIT">
```

I then want to check if the value is numeric or a string. I am doing this:

```
isDefined('understand') and isnumeric(understand)
```

But it always returns "NO".

Comment: why would `understand` be numeric?  When you set it as `<cfset understand = "http://www.example.com..."` it's obviously a string

Comment: as my question states, i want to search for construction=100 or construction=avent+construction+site. so if one of them is numeric as value, i should be able to get as yes or not.

Comment: You would need to create a list based on & as a delimiter and then loop through that checking each value.

Comment: Your example shows two potential variables named construction.  What if one is numeric and one is not?  Also, if the understand variable is the actual url of the page with this code, why do you need it?

Comment: at one time, it is always going to numeric and at other it is always be string, so no mix up

Comment: You need to show what you've done by way of solving your issue before you start asking for help. You ought to read this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html. Voting to close as this question show absolutely no evidence of actually trying to solve the problem before asking it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a good case for REGEX, but that's not my strength.  If you are always looking for the value of the same item (construction), you could take advantage of the underlying Java and use the [STRING.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method.  Then use the Coldfusion [val()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Val) function to see what you get.  The following solution assumes that 0 is not a valid value.  If it is then you have more work to do.

```
<cfscript>
    target=understand;
    //target=understand2;  //uncomment to try the second values
    token="construction=";
    potentialValues = target.split(token); //creates an array of values using the token as a separator
        for (item in potentialValues )
        {
            writeoutput(val(item) & "<br />");  //val will grab the numerical value and ignore everything that follows.  No number will become 0
        }
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
constructionIsAt = find(understand, "construction");
characterAfterConstruction = mid(understand, constructionIsAt + 13, 1);
if isNumeric(characterAfterConstruction) {
code for numeric
}
else {
code for non numeric
}
```